# \n breaks display with text, how to display line-breaks instead of \n text

Tags: php, sql

So, in database
database - > InnoDB
sava as -> text

Text from textarea are saved for example like that:"Awesome\nmake me rich\nnever give up"

So, php schould read \n as line-break, but i get pure text like in example above.

Part of a code i use to display data:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM card";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$text = $row['text'];
function main2($text){
    $this -> AddFont('DejaVu','','DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf',true);
    $this -> AddFont('DejaVu','B','DejaVuSansCondensed-Bold.ttf',true);
    $this -> SetFont('DejaVu','',14);
    $this -> Cell(200,10,$text,0,1,'C');
}
$pdf->main2($text)
```

I need to create pdf with generated data...

What i schould do?

Comment: Which PDF framework are you using in order to create the PDF?

Comment: fpdf, but when i put text in double quote to variable and pass it to function i have line-breaks but then i get same data from database i got \n... i it is not the framework fold i think

Answer (score 0):

I think `Cell` is not accepting normal line breaks.

You could remove every `\n` from your MySQL string and "substitute" it with `$fpdf->ln(height)` (see [FPDF Documentation](http://www.fpdf.org/en/tutorial/tuto3.htm)).

```
$str_arr = explode("\n", $text);

foreach($str_arr as $line) {
    $this->Cell(200, 10, $line, 0, 1, 'C');     
    $this->Ln(10); // end with line break   
}
```